# Accidently ran rm* command on root folder of OSX 10.6

Tags: osx-snow-leopard

As title says,I don't know what other harm has been done. All  i see my shell change from User/Myname to `-bash-3.2$`

I am scared to restart system. What Harm would have been done?

Comment: Based of knowledge from BSD/Linux, there is usually very few files, if any, in the root directory, except the kernel.  Which is critically important to boot.  Macs may be different.  If you did delete the kernel file in the OS's I've worked with more, that can have severe impact: you wouldn't be able to boot.  However, if something like that happens, know that the fix is relatively easy with the proper resources.  (You may need a boot disc, and/or another system running the same operating system, and/or swapping hard drives temporarily.  So some work, but not a full re-install, so don't panic)

Comment: I am able to boot and it seems bash and my user profile related items removed

Answer (score 1):

If it was `rm *`, you're probably OK. That won't delete directories, and there shouldn't be any important files in the root directory. There are three symlinks you should probably recreate, though -- var for private/var, tmp for private/tmp and etc for private/etc.

Comment: I get stuck on blue screen. Can you move this into apple forums?